# Watson Assistant context is not updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, chatbot, ibm-watson

I use watson assistant v1

My problem is that every time I make a call to the code in Nodejs, where I return the context, to have a coordinated conversation, the context is only updated once and I get stuck in a node of the conversation

this is my code

```
client.on('message', message => {
    //general variables
    var carpetaIndividual = <../../../>
    var cuerpoMensaje = <....>
    var emisorMensaje = <....>

//detect if context exists    
if(fs.existsSync(carpetaIndividual+'/contexto.json')) {
        var watsonContexto = require(carpetaIndividual+'/contexto.json');
        var variableContexto = watsonContexto;
    } else {
      var variableContexto = {} 
    }

//conection with Watson Assistant
assistant.message(
  {
    input: { text: cuerpoMensaje },
    workspaceId: '<>',
    context: variableContexto,
  })
  .then(response => {
    let messageWatson = response.result.output.text[0];
    let contextoWatson = response.result.context;
 
    console.log('Chatbot: ' + messageWatson);

    //Save and create JSON file for context
    fs.writeFile(carpetaIndividual+'/contexto.json', JSON.stringify(contextoWatson), 'utf8', function (err) {
      if (err) {
          console.error(err);
      }
    });
    
    //Send messages to my application
    client.sendMessage(emisorMensaje, messageWatson)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
client.initialize();
```

the context.json file is updated, but when it is read the code only reads the first update of the context.json file and not the other updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be because you are using `require` to read the .json file. For all subsequent `require`s of an already-required file, the data is cached and reused.

You will need to use `fs.readfile` and `JSON.parse`

```js
// detect if context exists    
if (fs.existsSync(carpetaIndividual+'/contexto.json')) {
  var watsonContexto = fs.readFileSync(carpetaIndividual+'/contexto.json');

  // Converting to JSON 
  var variableContexto = JSON.parse(watsonContexto); 
} else {
  var variableContexto = {} 
}
```

There is another subtle problem with your code, in that you are relying on
your async call to `fs.writeFile` completing before you read the file. This will be the case most of the time, but as you don't wait for the `fs.writeFile` to complete there is the chance that you may try to read the file, before it is written.

Comment: Thanks for the help if it worked, regarding the other problem with fs.writefile, how could I fix it with fs.writefilesync